# Problema al crear proyecto Application / Qt Widgets Application

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Cuando creo ese tipo de proyecto me sale el siguiente errr: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás compilando en Windows y con el compilador del Visual Studio... Ese compilador tienes que instalarlo de forma manual... ¿lo has hecho? Si no es así tienes que instalar el compilador de Visual Studio 2015... por lo que leo en los mensajes es la versión con la que intentas compilar

Comment: Puedes mostrar el .pro? Sin el .pro es difícil analizar el problema. Además, puedes expandir la carpeta del proyecto? Gracias.

Comment: soy nuevo en Qt, cual es el .pro?

Comment: tengo instalado Visual Studio Community 2017, como hago para que compile en este

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> tengo instalado Visual Studio Community 2017, como hago para que compile en este

El problema que tienes es que te has descargado la librería de Qt compilada con VS2015.

Qt te ofrece sus versiones precompiladas con varios compiladores. La gracia de usar estas librerías es que te ahorras el proceso de montarlas a mano... lo que te puede llevar fácil unas 6 horas.

En tu caso te has bajado la librería compilada para VS2015 mientras que únicamente tienes instalado VS2017. Lo que tienes que hacer es abrir la herramienta de mantenimiento de Qt y a través de esa herramienta desinstalar la versión de VS2015 y bajarte la de VS2017.

La herramienta de mantenimiento te presenta un árbol con todas las descargas posibles. En el caso de las librerías de Qt el primer nivel lo componen las diferentes versiones de Qt... si despliegas la versión 5.10.0 verás todas las versiones precompiladas que te ofrece Qt... deselecciona la versión para VS2015 y selecciona la que haya para VS2017. Después deja que la herramienta actualice el sistema y listo.

**NOTA** Te recomiendo cerrar QtCreator durante la actualización para que todos los componentes se puedan actualizar correctamente